# BCI EEG Python Mac OS X

Tags: python, machine-learning, python-requests, signal-processing, data-mining

I have mac os x and OpenBCI Device for EEG processing.

I would like to get data from OpenBCI realtime using Python. However, though I checked many things (OpenBCI website included). I couldn't find something particular works me.

If anyone know, please lead me in a simple and algorithmic way.

Thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at https://github.com/OpenBCI? I have no experience of it myself.

Comment: Some error logs may be helpful to resolve the problem.

Comment: @BillBell I have tried that but getting encoding problem. Trying to solve encoding problem while receiving data. I have also asked the BCI forum.

Comment: @shane I am tracking those but don't satisfy me :)))

Comment: I would say, put another question here on SO with full details of what you're experiencing. Code you've written, stack messages, etc. Even those who haven't used that particular product might be able to advise.

Comment: @BillBell I think you could take a look at the log of python and also OpenBCI.

Comment: Thank you @BillBell, I will put only code experiences. :)